# The angles of a triangle are as $1:2:7$, prove that the ratio of greatest side to least side is $\sqrt5+1:\sqrt5-1$. (Shouldn't that ratio be $7:1$?)

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

This problem is given in S.L. Loney's book on Plane Trigonometry.

> The angles of a triangle are as $1:2:7$, prove that the ratio of the greatest side to the least side is $\sqrt5 + 1 : \sqrt5 - 1$.

The way I reasoned is as follows: using the given angle ratio, we can introduce a proportionality constant, say, $A$; hence the three angles shall be $A$, $2A$, and $7A$. The problem requires to find the ratio of the greatest side to the least. The greatest side is that subtending the greatest angle, and the least - that subtending the least. Applying the Law of Sines then, if we call the greatest side $c$ and the least $a$, we have that $c : 7A :: a : A$, and alternately $c : a :: 7A : A$.

Then the ratio of $c : a$ - the greatest side to the least - is observed to be $7 : 1$. Why is this so? For what was supposed to be proved to be the ratio was $\sqrt5 + 1 : \sqrt5 - 1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you conclude that the sides are in the ratio $7:1?$ The sides will be in the ratio $\frac{\sin(7A)}{\sin(A)}.$ This follows from the sine rule. Then, we can solve for $A,$ using the angle sum property of triangles.

Comment: Given the ratios, you should be able to compute the actual angles of the triangle, then their sines.

Comment: $x+2x+7x=180^\circ$ This should help you to determine the angles.

Comment: Ratios of sides *almost-never* match ratios of angles. (The sole exception is when the ratio is $1$.) Consider, for instance, the $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle; the angles are in the proportion $1:2:3$, but the sides are $1:\sqrt{3}:2$. ... As I commented to someone recently: When you get down to it, the whole reason trigonometry exists as a subject is to bridge the *very* different behaviors between side-lengths and angle-measures in a triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Let the smallest angle in the triangle be $A$. Then, the other two angles are $2A,$ and $7A.$ Since in a triangle the angles sum up to $\pi,$ we have $10A=\pi.$ This leaves us with $A=\frac{\pi}{10}.$ Then, we apply the sine rule to get that the ratio of the largest side to the smallest side is $\frac{\sin(7A)}{\sin(A)}.$ This should be easy to compute, given that we know what $A$ is. Indeed, $\sin(7A)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4},$ and $\sin(A)=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}.$

Answer (score 1):

We use the Law of Sines, together with the fact that thecangles add up to $180°$.

Let $A$ be the smallest angle, so that the other angles measure $2A$and $7A$. Since all three angles sum to $80°$, we must have $A=18°$, thus $2A=36°$ and $7A=126°=180°-54°$.

The Law of Sines then gives the required ratio of the longest side (opposite the $7A$ angle) to the shortest side (opposite $A$):

$\dfrac{\sin126°}{\sin18°}=\dfrac{\sin54°}{\sin18°}$

where we note that **supplementary angles have the same sine.**

There are many ways to get the sines of $18°$ and $54°$, typically involving the use of geometry combined with basic trigonometric identities. Pictured below is a regular pentagon combined with a rectangle, setting off a pair of colored right triangles.

[image]

Applying the SAH COA TOA rule to each triangle and comparing lengths leads to the result

$\sin54°-\sin18°=1/2.$

We then apply the sum-product formula for the product of two sines:

$\sin18°\sin54°=(1/2)(\cos36°-\cos72°)=(1/2)(\sin54°-\sin18°)=1/4.$

Thus the numbers $\sin54°$ and $-\sin18°$ have a sum of $1/2$ and a product of $-1/4$, so they must he the roots of the quadratic equation

$4x^2-2x-1=0,$

with positive root $\sin54°=(1+\sqrt5)/4$ and negative root $-\sin18°=(1-\sqrt5)/4$. Plugging these results into the side ratio given above leads to the claimed result. (They might have simplified the ratio to $(3+\sqrt5)/2$.)

Answer (score 0):

The interior angles of a triangle always add up to 180°, so the angles must be 18°, 36°, and 126°.  By the Law of Sines, the ratio between the longest and smallest sides is $\frac{\sin 126°}{\sin 18°}$.

---

If you don't know the trig function values for multiples of 18°, you can use DeMoivre's Theorem:

$$(\cos 18° + i\sin 18°)^5 = \cos 90° + i\sin 90°$$

For brevity, let $c := \cos 18°$ and $s := \sin 18°$.  Then:

$$(c + is)^5 = i$$
$$c^5 + 5isc^4 - 10s^2c^3 - 10is^3c^2 + 5s^4c + is^5 = i$$

Breaking this equation down into separate real and imaginary parts gives:

$$c^5 - 10s^2c^3 + 5s^4c = 0$$
$$5sc^4 - 10s^3c^2 + s^5 = 1$$

But by the Pythagorean identity, we have $c^2 + s^2 = 1$, which lets us frame each equation in terms of a single variable:

$$c^5 - 10(1 - c^2)c^3 + 5(1 - c^2)^2c = 0$$
$$5s(1 - s^2)^2 - 10s^3(1 - s^2) + s^5 = 1$$

Or, after a bit of algebra:

$$16c^5 - 20c^3 + 5c = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$16s^5 - 20s^3 + 5s - 1 = 0 \tag{2}$$

Equation (1) has the root $c = 0$.  Factoring it out gives the biquadratic equation $16(c^2)^2 - 20c^2 + 5 = 0$, which can be solved to get $c = \pm \sqrt{\frac{5 \pm \sqrt{5}}{8}}$.  But we know $\cos(30°) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} < \cos(18°) = c < \cos(0) = 1$, so $c = \sqrt{\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{8}} \approx 0.951057$ is the only solution that makes sense.

Similarly, equation (2) has the root $s = 1$.  Factoring out $s - 1$ gives $16s^4 + 16s^3 - 4s^2 - 4s + 1 = 0$.  That quartic has no rational roots, but does factor into $(4s^2 + 2s - 1)^2 = 0$, giving $s = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}$.  But only the positive root makes sense, so $s = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}$.  Therefore,

$$\cos(18°) = \sqrt{\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{8}} \approx 0.951057 $$
$$\sin(18°) = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} \approx 0.309017$$

Applying the double-angle formulas $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$, we obtain:

$$\cos(36°) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} \approx 0.809017$$
$$\sin(36°) = \sqrt{\frac{5 - \sqrt{5}}{8}} \approx 0.587785$$

Finally, note that $\sin(126°) = \sin(36° + 90°) = \cos(36°) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}$.

---

Using the trig function values from the previous section, we get:

$$\frac{\sin(126°)}{\sin(18°)} = \frac{\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}}{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{\sqrt{5} - 1}$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that their angle ratios are $1:2:7$ implies that their angles are $18^{\circ}, 36^{\circ} $ and $ 126^{\circ}$. Let their opposite sides be $a,b $ and $c$, then by sine law, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{c}{a} & =\frac{\sin 54^{\circ}}{\sin 18^{\circ}} \\
& =\frac{3 \sin 18^{\circ}-4 \sin ^3 18^{\circ}}{\sin 18^{\circ}} \\
& =3-4 \sin ^2 18^{\circ} \\
& =1+2 \cos 36^{\circ}
\end{aligned}
$$
Noting that $$
\cos 36^{\circ}-\cos 72^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Then $$
\begin{gathered}
4 \cos ^2 36^{\circ}-2 \cos 36^{\circ}-1=0 \Rightarrow 
\cos 36^{\circ}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}
\end{gathered}
$$
Hence $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{c}{a} & =1+2\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right) \\
& =\frac{6+2 \sqrt{5}}{4} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{5}-1}
\end{aligned}
$$